# Invalid WatchKit Support - The bundle contains an invalid implementation of WatchKit

Tags: apple-watch

I am trying to upload my apple watch app to iTunes, every time i am uploading my binary i am getting following mail from apple team.I have done with my following checklist.

- Created separate App id and profile for watchapp and extension.
- I have the correct set of images for apple watch as well as iOS app.
- my app was initially built with Xcode 6.2 SDK and now i am submitting with 6.3 SDK.

Don't know where i am doing wrong. can anyone with experience help me out here.

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "XXXXX". To process your delivery, the following issues must be
>   corrected:
>
> Invalid WatchKit Support - The bundle contains an invalid
>   implementation of WatchKit. The app may have been built or signed with
>   non-compliant or pre-release tools. Visit developer.apple.com for more
>   information.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the
>   corrected binary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was that the "IOS Deployment Target" in Build Settings for my WatchKit App and my WatchKit Extension were not both the same.  My extension was set to 8.3 and my WatchKit App was set to 8.2.  Once I set them both to 8.2 the error went away and the WatchKit App installed just fine.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading apple watch app, it need to have apple watch extension into embedded binary of iOS app. But if you are habbitat to delete derived data then xcode6 will delete that target. and when you submit it to apple it will only get ios app not apple watch app.[image]

Adding Embedded Binaries fails in Xcode
Xcode won't link framework form separate project
App crashes on device because of missing framework, works in simulator
Overview

After deleting the "DerivedData" folder (or performing a "Product > Clean") in xcode6, I cannot add CocoaTouch frameworks from another project to the "Embedded Binary" section (under General tab).

Or, Xcode hits a linker error because it cannot find a framework that if previously could.

Other symptoms

Clicking on the + under "Embedded Binaries" shows the Framework selector but selecting a framework in different project in the workspace does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been tearing my hair out over this one too. Here's what I've tried:

1. I've generated new provisioning profiles for the app, the watchkit extension, and the watchkit app, using unique bundle identifiers for each (com.example.app, com.example.app.watchkitextension & com.example.app.watchkitapp) and a distribution certificate. Downloaded, installed, and set each target to its own provisioning profile in Build Settings > Provisioning. Tried explicitly setting signing authority AND leaving it on automatic.
2. I've confirmed that the xcarchive contains a WatchKitSupport directory and WK file when I Show Package Contents of the archive
3. I've ensured that WatchKit Extension, WatchKit app, and IOS app all have matching build and version numbers
4. I ran Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax... on the app, extension, and watchkit targets (no source changes were required in my case..)
5. I've compiled from scratch, cleaned, built, & archived, rinsed and repeated, restarted system and looped again.

In my case, none of those worked. Hope one of them helps you. And if any other kind soul out there has fixed this without going bald, share the hair, man, share the hair.

Comment: Have you tried my answer above becasue thats the only thing which can solve this problem, let me know if you need any details for my answer above.

Comment: Sorry, Gaurav, I understand your answer up to "adding Embedded Binaries Fails in Xcode" but nothing after that .. I did try embedding the Watchkit Extension in the companion app, but I get an error of "error: WatchKit Extension doesn't contain any WatchKit apps. Verify that the value of WKWatchKitApp in your WatchKit App's Info.plist is set to YES." I did verify it, it IS set to YES.

Comment: Yes, this is just a random error i am still getting, i solved this by two way by setting provisioning profile and by doing clean of xcode.

Comment: I basically rebuilt my app as a new project in 6.3.1 and have managed to submit it successfully. There were several differences in the builds, but one noticeable difference was indeed that the Watchkit Extension appears as an embedded binary in the companion app for the successful build. I too set my provisioning files and cleaned, but could not embed that binary. The rebuild in a new project was my desperation move, but that worked in the end.